# Many-to-one with primary key (unique constraint)

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I've got an Article and a Category model linked by a many-to-one relationship. However, the Category model has a unique constraint on the id property because it's the primary key as you can see below.

```
class Article: Object
{
    dynamic var id: String = ""
    dynamic var title: String = ""
    dynamic var category: Category()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class Category: Object
{
    dynamic var id: String = ""
    dynamic var title: String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

This will work until an Article got the same Category and throw an exception because of the unique constraint.

How am I supposed to implement this kind of relationship ? Is there any built-in way to persist only the Category id and retrieve the corresponding Category ?

Thanks

Comment: Be sure to use `Realm.create(object, update: true)` if you want to update existing objects that have primary keys

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in Realm doc (0.92.1), you have to use a `List<Object>` for a many-to-one relationship.

See this link :

http://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

```
class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var owner: Person? // Can be optional
}
    class Person: Object {
        ... // other property declarations
        let dogs = List<Dog>()
    }

    let someDogs = Realm().objects(Dog).filter("name contains 'Fido'")
    jim.dogs.extend(someDogs)
    jim.dogs.append(rex)
```

So in your case, I guess it should be something like that :

```
   class Article: Object
{
    dynamic var id: String = ""
    dynamic var title: String = ""
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
class Category: Object
{
    dynamic var id: String = ""
    dynamic var title: String = ""
    dynamic var articles = List<Article>()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

If your Realm version is older :

```
 class Category: Object
    {
       ...
        dynamic var categories = RLMArray(objectClassName: Article.className())

    }
```

Comment: That's what I did in the first place and it gave me the same error `Can't set primary key property 'id' to existing value '551a850d9a5f63d106dd4b30'.` It's working fine when you don't have constraint on the id property but that's not my goal :/

Comment: Could you edit your original post to share more of the code that is causing the error?

Comment: I fixed my answer because I did a mistake between article and category.
Maybe my new update will work.
And yes more code would help! If you can show how you create and store your objects.

Comment: Oh my god, i'm so stupid and i'm so sorry. It's the `id` of the `Article` model which was messing with me ...

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Did you fix the issue?

Comment: I was obsessed about the primary key of the Category that I wasn't thinking anymore about the primary key of the Article model. This error `Can't set primary key property 'id' to existing value '551a850d9a5f63d106dd4b30'` was about the Article id not the Category id. Thanks for your help :)